# Which rights are necessary for using borg repository as non privileged user

Tags: linux, backup

I'd like to use borg as a backup solution. I only like to back up home directory, so I run borg as non privileged user. Which rights do I need to assign to the borg repository to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, borg-backup will need read/write access, plus the ability to access the directory.  So minimum permissions would be 0700 (u+rwx) on the directory for the user account which is running the borg-backup command.

Note that if the borg repo is located on an always-mounted file system, which can be written to by the current user, your backups are vulnerable to mishaps like accidental deletion or cryptolocker malware.